# how to continue on react port 3000 after OAuth 2.0 callback fired in django port 8000

Tags: python, reactjs, django, api, spotify

My application is built by React frontend and Django backend.

Although the React part is in the frontend folder inside Django project, I try to make both parts as independent as they can.

So basically, Django only server as API provider, and React control the entire frontend.

In the dev mode, Django run on localhost with port 8000; React run on port 3000.
I have completed CORS setting in my setting.py

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000'
]
```

So basically, I can test both frontend and backend quite independently. All Api fetching also works properly between Django and React.

However, in my app, I also need to connect to Spotify API to do something.
During the authentication process, I need to provide Redirect url for Spotify authentication callback.

The url I register in Spotify is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-spotify/callback
```

in my urls.py:

```
from .views import get_auth_callback

urlpatterns = [
    path('callback', get_auth_callback),

]
```

In view.py:

```
def get_auth_callback(request):
    code = request.GET.get('code')

    response = post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', data={
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': env.str('REDIRECT_URL'),
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'client_id': env.str('CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret': env.str('CLIENT_SECRET')
    }).json()

    access_token = response.get('access_token')
    token_type = response.get('token_type')
    refresh_token = response.get('refresh_token')
    expires_in = response.get('expires_in')
    
    edit_user_token(request.session.session_key, refresh_token, access_token, expires_in, token_type)
    return redirect('/')
```

The problem is in the final line:

```
  return redirect('/')
```

If I login Spotify from my frontend (port 3000), the redirect link will bring me to the port 8000 because the redirect callback function is setup in Django.

And my testing in port 3000 can no longer continue.

Is there any solution for such issue?
Or I need to always do npm run build and test everything only in port 8000?

Comment: But why are you redirecting instead you can send json response with some status code to frontend and then do redirection from frontend if found certain status code ?

Comment: I am sharing the same problem , I am returning the response to the callback but I need to make it to the frontend . How do i do that . I am trying to implement server side flow for better security .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-spotify/callback

You have to register a new url in Spotify for the test port:
http://127.0.0.1:3000/api-spotify/callback